# How to save output from for loop to a List in Python?

Tags: python, xml, list

I have a for loop that generates strings associated with the number in the numbers list by searching through an XML file.

```
tree = parse("demo.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

fields = {int(child.attrib["number"]): child.attrib["name"] for child in root}

numbers [1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 45, 78]

for number in numbers:
    print(fields.get(number, f"{number} does not exist in XML"))
```

so the output is like:

```
Account
Name
ID
Time
```

I want to save this output to a list, and separate each text by a comma, so it should save this to a list that should look like:

myList: [Account, Name, ID, Time]

How can I do this?

Comment: MyList format isn't right for string, I mean the items in the list should have quotes around them too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension

```
myList = [fields.get(number, f"{number} does not exist in XML") for number in numbers]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new empty list before starting the loop and add elements to it inside the loop body.

Replace

```
for number in numbers:
   print(fields.get(number, f"{number} does not exist in XML"))
```

with

```
myList = []
for number in numbers:
    myList.append(fields.get(number, f"{number} does not exist in XML")))
```

You can then use `myList` to get the output in the format you like. From your question, it seems you may need one of these

```
print("myList:", myList)
print("myList: [", ",".join(myList), "]")
```